Shimano Megarange freewheel rubbing on guide pulley in 2nd gear
So I’m building up a Trek 7000 (1999? possibly) mtb frame. I’ve set it up as a 1x. I’ve encountered an issue during pedaling in 2nd gear. When in 2nd gear, a portion of the guide pulley (near its axle where it flares out slightly) rubs on the edge of the teeth of the 1st gear. I’ve played with chain length and B-screw a lot, but nothing seems to help enough. I’ve even went and “borrowed” a longer B-screw off of one of my other derailleurs from the parts bin. Still not helping. Any suggestions?

Can you be more accurate about the exact setup? If you converted a derailleur from a 3x and kept it as is for a 1x, the most likely answer is that the rear derailleur is not designed for the cassette. And if you manage to get it to work with an inadequate derailleur, shifting performance on the small cogs will be horrible.

Probably got a bent hanger. Check and adjust with the correct tool.
